# Анимация рисования линий - canvas, js

Tags: javascript, canvas

Здравствуйте. Скажу сразу, что я начинающий программист.
В чем суть: я хочу чтобы при скролле вниз у меня рисовался плавно контур (т.е. какое-то изображение в виде контура) и дойдя до конкретной области изображение должно полностью отрисоваться, если скроллить обратно вверх, то контур наоборот должен стираться. Для начала я хочу просто получить плавно рисующийся контур (в данном примере это совокупность прямых - линейных кривых Безье). В итоге я словил ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" на строке c комментарием //error. Я не могу понять, почему не могу получить массив значений и отрисовать контур. Пожалуйста, помогите :(

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var getLineTo = function(myArr, step) {

    if(step === undefined) {
        step = 0.001;
    }
    var arr = [];
    for (var t = 0; t < 1 + step; t += step) {
        if (t > 1) {
            t = 1;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length - 1; i++) {
            var bx,
                by;
            bx = myArr[i][0] + t *(myArr[i+1][0] - myArr[i][0]); //error
            by = myArr[i][1] + t *(myArr[i+1][1] - myArr[i][1]); 

            arr[i] = [bx, by];
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

var drowLines = function(ctx, arr, delay, pause) {
    if (delay === undefined) {
        delay = 20;
    }
    if (pause === undefined) {
        pause = delay;
    }

    function delayDraw() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            ctx.moveTo(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(arr[i+1][0], arr[i+1][1]);
            ctx.stroke();
            if (delay > 0) {
                setTimeout(delayDraw, delay);
            } else {
                delayDraw();
            }
        }
    }

    if (pause > 0) {
        setTimeout(delayDraw, pause);
    } else {
        delayDraw();
    }
}

var myArray1 = [[10, 10], [100, 100], [158, 250]];
var mass;
mass = getLineTo(myArray1);
drowLines(ctx, mass, 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в этом месте `myArr[i+1][0]` превышает количество в массиве на последнем элементе. `myArr.length` возвращает количество а начинаете вы с 0.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length - 1; i++)
```